# Implement abstract class with constrained generic in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

Working on Kotlin 1.3.61

Having this code:

```
abstract class ResourceObserver<T> : Observer<T> where T : Resource<T> {
    override fun onChanged(t: T) {
        when (t.status) {
            Status.LOADING -> { ... }
            Status.ERROR -> { ... }
            Status.SUCCESS -> { onSuccess(t.data) }
        }
    }

    abstract fun onSuccess(data: T?)
}
```

and trying to implement it

```
private val foo = object : ResourceObserver<Resource<Bar>> {
    override fun onSuccess(data: Bar?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Compiler (Android Studio in this case) gives me this error:

```
Type argument is not within its bounds.
Expected: Resource<Resource<Bar>>
Found: Resource<Bar>
```

What is wrong with my obviously erroneous code?

Comment: Keep giving me the error, this time is: `Type argument is not within its bounds.
Expected: Resource<Bar>
Found: Bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint `where T : Resource<T>` indeed requires that whatever type argument you use for `T` must also be `Resource<T>` (with `T` substituted by the type itself).

According to this constraint, the type argument that you provide for the implementation `T := Resource<Bar>` is checked for being `Resource<T> ≡ Resource<Resource<Bar>>` and fails this check.

For this constraint and the subtype to work, `Bar` would need to be a subtype (implementation) of `Resource<Bar>`.

Do you really need `T` to be a `Reosurce<T>` *with the same `T`*? Will it solve your problem if you use an upper bound with a [star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) `T : Resource<*>` or add another type parameter, as shown below?

```
abstract class ResourceObserver<T, R> : Observer<T> where T : Resource<R> { ... }
```

```
private val foo = object : ResourceObserver<Resource<Bar>, Bar> { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an attempt to use [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification). For it to work you need to

1. make `Bar` extend `Resource<Bar>`;
2. make `private val foo = object : ResourceObserver<Bar> { ... }` instead of `<Resource<Bar>>`.

Usually `Resource` itself will be declared with the similar constraint

```
class Resource<T : Resource<T>>
```

so if you forget to do 1 `Bar` won't compile.